# Open Sound Control (OSC) Arrays in Rug.OSC in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, osc

I'm writing some code in C# using the Rug.OSC library for Open Sound Control or OSC. I have been successfully sending OSC messages from it to other code in Processing, etc., but only single or short lists of floats or ints, not arrays. I have a fairly large array (1462 floats) that I want to send as an array in one message rather than 1462 single float messages, but I get nothing but errors in MSVS.

What I want to do in C# code is essentially this:

float[] myArray = new float[1462];
myOscMessage = new OscMessage("/array", myArray);

I've looked at the syntax found here:

https://bitbucket.org/rugcode/rug.osc/wiki/Message%20arguments%20as%20Rug.Osc%20understands%20them

and have tried syntax like:

myOscMessage = new OscMessage("/array", {myArray});

--or--

myOscMessage = new OscMessage("/array", new float[]{myArray});

--or--

myOscMessage = new OscMessage("/array", new float[]{new float[]{myArray}});

but I get errors like:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Rug.Osc.dll

-- or --

can't convert float[] to float

I'm probably missing simple here, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions about how to send an array of floats via OSC in C# using the Rug.OSC library?

Comment: Also it should be noted that it is not possible to send 1462 floats in a single message via UDP with Rug.Osc in its default setup as it would exceed the maximum packet size. It amounts to more than 7310 bytes because a typetag entry is written for each array element. It would probably be better to send as a `byte[]` (blob) as there would be minimal type tag overhead. You may also have to think about slicing your array up or use a non-udp transport layer like TCP.

Answer (score 3):

Currently it is not possible to use an array of type `float` as a argument in the `OscMessage` constructor. It is however possible to use `object[]`.

You can cast `float[]` to `object[]` using the code below.

```
float[] floats = new float[] { 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 9f, 10f }; 

// cast float array into an object array            
object[] objects = floats.Cast<object>().ToArray();            

OscMessage message = new OscMessage("/test", objects);
```

The contents of `message` will be `/test, 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, 6f, 7f, 9f, 10f`

I will look into adding the capability to create messages with array arguments of any valid OSC type in the next release.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Rug.Osc